# Подскажите функции, которые нужно использовать

Tags: google-apps-script

Задача заключается в следующем.
1)Нужно, чтобы пользователь увидел надпись "введите email"
2) и после ввода email ему должен высветиться соответствующий этому email код

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться и какие функции нужно использовать для этого. С программированием не особо дружу.

Comment: Опишите среду, в которой это должно происходить.

Comment: Google apps script. Спасибо

Comment: Где это все происходит? Это опубликованное приложение, API, Таблицы?

Comment: Гугл таблицы. Имеется таблица с email и соответствующим для этого email кодом. Нужно, чтобы пользователь перешёл по этой ссылке и увидел сообщение введите email и получил свой код.

Comment: Яснее не стало. Таблица доступна пользователям или нет? Если нет, то вопрос серды остается открытым - описание неполное. Если да, то какой смысл городить какие-то ссылки?

Answer (score 1):

И опять и снова советую изучить официальную [документацию](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) GAS. Там все очень неплохо структурировано и описано.

Общий алгоритм в вашем случае будет таков:

1. Вывести сообщению юзеру со строкой ввода данных, например, через [inputBox(prompt)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputBox(String)), [inputBox(prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputBox(String,ButtonSet)) или [inputBox(title, prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String,String,ButtonSet))
2. Считать введенную юзером инфо. И если это валидный имейл из вашего списка, то выдать нужную инфо [msgBox(prompt)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String)), [msgBox(prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String,ButtonSet)) или [msgBox(title, prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String,String,ButtonSet))

P.S. Спасибо справедливому замечанию [oshliaer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178725/oshliaer) про то, откуда запускаются данные скрипты:

> Возможно, стоит добавить, что Class Ui требует окружения приложения. А
>   для webapp есть только HtmlService

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить, что Class Ui требует окружения приложения. А для webapp есть только HtmlService.